# Training runs out of memory as RAM consumption keeps growing

Tags: tensorflow

I am not sure since when am having this issue and I have to believe that this happened at some point between today and a few months ago but it would seem that the RAM (CPU) consumption grows over time during epochs.

```py
self.model.fit(
    train_data,
    initial_epoch=self.status.valid_last.epoch,
    epochs=train_config.epochs,
    steps_per_epoch=train_config.steps_per_epoch,
    callbacks=self._get_experiment_callbacks(),
    validation_data=valid_data,
    validation_steps=train_config.validation_steps,
)
```

The only thing out of the ordinary here might be the callbacks I am passing but there's actually nothing special here. One is a `TensorBoard` (TB) callback and the other is a custom `Metric` which is not doing much except plotting the learning rate and other general metrics to TB.

```py
    def _get_experiment_callbacks(self) -> List[tf.keras.callbacks.Callback]:
        tensorboard_cb = tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(
            log_dir=os.path.join(out_dir, "logs"),
            update_freq="epoch",
            profile_batch=profile_batch,
            write_images=True,
        )

        # Not interested in whatever is plotted in those
        tensorboard_cb.on_epoch_end = lambda *args: ...
        tensorboard_cb.on_test_end = lambda *args: ...

        return [
            tensorboard_cb,
            Metrics(tensorboard_cb, update_freq=100),
        ]
```

This leaves us with the last suspect which is the `valid_data` itself. This is essentially just a list of protobuf files (shards) which I am loading like so:

```py
def load_shards(
    decode_example_fn: Callable,
    shard_fps: List[str],
    training: bool,
    buffer_size: int = None # 50 * 1000 ** 2,
) -> tf.data.Dataset:
    if not len(shard_fps) > 0:
        raise ValueError("Argument shard_fps must be a list to shards but is empty.")

    def make_dense_(example):
        for k, v in example.items():
            if isinstance(v, tf.SparseTensor):
                example[k] = tf.sparse.to_dense(v)
        return example

    def load_records_(filenames):
        record_dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(filenames, buffer_size=buffer_size)
        record_dataset = record_dataset.map(decode_example_fn)
        record_dataset = record_dataset.map(make_dense_)
        return record_dataset

    if not training:
        shard_fps = sorted(shard_fps)

    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(tf.constant(shard_fps))
    options = tf.data.Options()
    options.experimental_distribute.auto_shard_policy = tf.data.experimental.AutoShardPolicy.DATA
    dataset = dataset.with_options(options)

    if training:
        dataset = dataset.interleave(load_records_, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE, deterministic=False)
    else:
        dataset = dataset.apply(load_records_)

    dataset = dataset.prefetch(tf.data.AUTOTUNE)

    return dataset
```

and from then on there's just preprocessing and transformation mappings on the inputs. So.. I would not expect any memory leak at this point

Still, I am observing a continuous increase of memory consumption over time. The screenshot below shows the consumption after a restart.

At first we use ~28GB of RAM. After 100 steps there's a sharp increase, to ~33GB and from there it kind of seems to stabilize at around 38GB. The next big jump at 216k steps is coming from an evaluation. From there it's just constantly growing ..

From the looks it appears as if the memory usage stabilized and the jump only occurs after each epoch (1 epoch = 6000 steps).

[image]

Comment: So, the usages of RAM (physical ram and not GPU-RAN) is incrementing due to validation data? Is it?

Comment: @M.Innat after further inspection it turns out that the increase in memory does occur _during_ epochs.. No idea what's happening here exactly.

Comment: Have you tried this: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/config/experimental/set_memory_growth#for_example?

Comment: @M.Innat I don't think this is related to my issue. I am running in OOM on the CPU, not GPU.

Comment: Does the consumed memory scale up linearly with `buffer_size`?

Comment: @0x90 Hm, that's hard to tell. I am using bucketing by sequence length so it's not straight forward to tell I guess. But from the looks of the updated graph it seems that the RAM usage increases only at the end of each epoch after some time. As if the validation dataset gets allocated but never release ..

Answer (score 0):

There could be any number of things that could be wrong. TensorBoard could possibly not be reusing the same graph, but instead is adding graphs, which leads to OOM. I don't use TensorBoard myself because I remember this as happening to me a few years back. It's also possible that using `model.fit` is the problem and that you're loading your data at every epoch. You could try writing the training loop something like:

```
for epoch in tf.range(epochs):
   batch_train_loss = []
   batch_train_acc = []
   for batch, (X, Y) in train_dataset.enumerate():
       train_loss = train_fn(X, Y, model, loss, optimizer, metric, batch)  # do the actual training
       train_acc = metric.result().numpy()  # get the training accuracy
       batch_train_loss.append(train_loss)  # save the training loss above
       batch_train_acc.append(train_acc)  # save the training accuracy above
       metric.reset_states()  # reset the metric after every batch
```

where the `train_fn` is:

```
def get_apply_train_fn():
    @tf.function
    def train_function(X, Y, model, loss, optimizer, metric, step):
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            predictions = model(X, training=True)
            loss_value = loss(Y, predictions)

        gradients = tape.gradient(loss_value, model.trainable_variables)
        optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, model.trainable_variables))
        train_acc = metric.update_state(Y, predictions)
        return loss_value

    return train_function

train_fn = get_apply_train_fn()
```

Now, this is a stupidly complicated way of writing `model.fit`, but it does work.
Another way in which I've had to combat OOM on GPU side is use Python's multiprocessing, but this was in a context where I was doing 10-fold cross-validation and the training would crash after 7 or 8 folds with OOM.

Alternatively, you could try turning eager execution on or off with

```
tf.config.run_functions_eagerly(False)  # or True
```